# Problem with User /SQL Permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, permissions

Please forgive me if this post is in the wrong place, but as your all the cleverest bunch of guys I know, advice would be appreciated.

Another user in my company wrote [and on another pc], installed the new application [written in vb.net I think - but maybe c#].

He left the company a month a go, and I have now started to get problems [or rather notice them for the first time] - the files were being logged to SQL Server on the network.  Now I notice that a month ago the Network SQL Server 2008 has not been logging the data, but in fact it has been accumulating under SQL 2005 on the local machine that the software is installed on, and the temp file is over 100mb big...

I suspect that the IT department froze his account when he left, and this disrupted the SQL access and program network permissions.  The Event Viewer seems to support this theory by logging red critical errors that basically say [unable to connect to SQL server etc etc].

The program runs now as a guest [It always ran as a guest]. So I cant see how freezing or deleting his account would affect things.

Do you know how I can fix this without re-installing everything?

Thanks in advance.
Jim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a couple of things to check for starters:

- what accounts the SQL services on the machine are running under e.g. http://sql-articles.com/articles/general/sql-server-service-accounts
- which account is the application logging in as

Comment: Oh I found out the local 2005 SQL Server is pushing the data to the main 2008 Server - this is where the errors are occuring.

Comment: The SQL Services are running under the 'Local System' Account.
The local system Account is a Guest Account [Company needs the reduced functionality - we cant let the user play with the pc, sadly]

Comment: Ok - Thanks for the reply - I will go and read the article. :D

Comment: The network guy got it working.
SQL Server 2005 -SQL Service runs as Local Machine -Replication service runs as domain admin